# How to pass tensor object to a function which accepts images with datatype uint

Tags: python, keras

I am passing a batch of images to deep neural network and from that I am  getting some output in the form of tensors. Now I want to pass this tensor value to some function which accepts the input in the form of uint and can process single image at a time. Suppose I have output like this: (4,320,320,3), I want to iterate on the first dimension i.e. on 4. So, it will read single image each time and pass to that function.

Comment: Hi shailza, welcome to Stackoverflow. It helps if you show us what you have tried so far and what the problem was with your method.

Comment: you can use `preprocessing_function=your_function` in `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` , which will do exactly what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your function to `ImageDataGenerator` in following way

```
def my_custom_function(image):
     .....
    return output
```

Then pass this function to `ImageDataGenerator`

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    ......
    preprocessing_function=my_custom_function,
    .....
)
```

This will take each of your image, apply your custom function on that image, apply other transformation, you provided using `ImageDataGenerator`. The benefit of it is that you don't need to explicitly use a for loop to apply your function on single image